# LINQ query to return true if associated (related) record exists for each person

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a People object with a related (associated) table of FavoritePeople. The FavoritePeople object just stores the UserId and PersonId so we know which people are a users favorites.

I'm using Entity Framework 4.2 with Code First and I have mapped all of the fields in People except for IsFavorite which a Boolean and my idea was to set this to true if a related record existed in FavoritePeople.

I'd like to return all the people records with the correct value in the IsFavorite column.

Although I can work out how to do this in SQL, I'm stuck on how to do this in LINQ!

Any suggestions?

Comment: question is not quite clear - what is the "associated record" ?

Comment: Basically, by associated I meant if a record existed for a Person in the FavoritePeople table then set the IsFavorite field to true in the People table for that Person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have a property for FavoritePeople, you may be able to..

```
public bool IsFavorite {get{return FavoritePeople.Any();}}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyron, that's a great answer for dealing with it on an individual record basis, but I need to do this for the entire collection.

Comment: @Mitch - If you have a collection of People, I would then just iterate over the collection and get the "IsFavorite" value for each one. You can then do with it as you please. You won't be able to use an individual property to handle an entire collection.

Comment: @JasCav - Thanks for your comment. Maybe my whole approach to this is wrong then. I just wanted to display a checkbox in a list of people to show whether each person is on the current users favorites list. I would have thought this was a fairly common situation with some well established ways of doing it (with LINQ).

Comment: Thanks to tyrongower and JasCav for their comments. I decided to go with their suggestions and use FavoritePeople.Any() in a foreach loop. Not sure if it's the most efficient way to do it but it works! Here's the code

Comment: var people = from x in db.People
    select x;     
    foreach(Person person in people)
    {
        if (person.FavoritePeople.Any()) person.IsPinned = true;
    }        
return people;

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough rep to comment so I'll reply with an answer;

Going with Tyron's solution will give you horrible performance if you select multiple People.

You should either eagerly load the FavoritePeople reference with `.Include(x => x.FavoritePeople)` when querying for People (warning: chance of huge dataset from db)
 OR (preferably) rewrite your query to include IsFavorite:

```
ctx.Peoples.Select(x => new 
{ 
     x.Name, 
     IsFavorite = x.FavoritePeople.Any()
});
```